# Spark is slow when parsing columner json

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have huge  Columnar Json file with 10gb data.

It has 65 columns
And data look like

{
"Heue": {"0":"77448".......},

"Heue1": {"0":"788".......}
.....
}

When I am trying to load this in spark data frame it fails always with memory issue.

So defined schema with String Type.

With string type I was able to load data but .

It render like

```
+-------------+----------- ----------------
Heue            | Heue1 |
+---------------+---------+-----------------
|{"0":"77448".......}  | {"0":"788".......}
+-------------------------------------------
```

Entire value as dict in one row of dataframe.

To short out as I used MapType  withColumn and explode function.
Like below .

```
df.withColumn(
"Heue", explode(map_values("Heue"))
).select("Heue")
```

This give  dict data in rows but when I do it for 30 columns it is fialing after 30 mins stating executor issue.

Can anyone can guide me what could be the best way to load this data, what might I am doing wrong here.

```
DRIVER MEMORY 10 G 
DRIVER CORE 15 
Executor Core 5 
Executor memory 15G
```